# CHS to LBA mapping - (Disk Storage)

Tags: filesystems, storage, disk, hard-drive, sector

Before LBA you simply had the physical mapping of a disk, which on originally on an old a IBM-PC compatible machine would look something like this the following:

- ***Cylinder Number :*** (10-bits)

  - 0-1024 (1024 = 2^10)
- ***Head Number :***    (8-bits)

  - 0-256 (256 = 2^8)
- ***Sector Number* :**  (6-bits)

  - 0 is reserved typically for the "*[boot sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector)*" (***c***-0,***h***-0,***s***-0)
  - 1-64 (63 = 2^6 - 1) *0 is reserved

***Total CHS address bits :*** 24-Bits

---

Back in day the average (file|block|sector) size was 512B.

Example from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector):

```
512(bytes) × 63(sectors) x 256(heads) × 1024(cylinders) = 8064 MiB (yields what is known as 8 GiB limit)
```

What I'm confused on is what a *head* actually means, when referred to as  `heads-per-cylinder` in the LBA formula. It doesn't make sense to me because from what I know a head is *[head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_read-and-write_head)*, and unless it removable media each *platter* has two of them (top,bottom) for each of the it's  surfaces.

[image]

In my mind it would make more since to referred to them as `heads-per-disk` or `heads-per-surface`, since a cylinder goes through the entire disk (multiple platters).

[image]

---

**Logical Block Addressing:**

Formula: `A = (c ⋅ Nheads + h) ⋅ Nsectors + (s − 1)`

- `A` - Logical Block Address
- `Nheads` - Number of heads on a disk `heads-per-disk`
- `Nsectors` - Numbers of sectors on a track `sectors-per-track`
- `c,h,s` - is the cylinder,head,sector numbers `24-bits total (10+8+6)`

Looking at the first example on [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector):

```
For geometry 1020 16 63 of a disk with 1028160 sectors CHS 3 2 1 is LBA  3150=(3× 16+2)× 63
```

***Geometry:***

- Cylinder Number - 1020 (0-1024)
- Head Number - 16 (0-256)
- Sector Number - 63 (1-64)

How are these ***geometry*** CHS number mapping in to the CHS tuple (3,2,1) to be used in this formula?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think heads is a number to be taken too literally.  I've taken a few apart to salvage the neodymium magnets and only ever seen one disk, except on big 5-1/4 inch drives.  And 2 heads.  And cylinders start at 0 but heads and sectors start at 1.  Some early Windows versions could only deal with 255 heads so the numbers get played with.

Short answer: Multiply cylinder # times head # times sector # and it's close to LBA.  I tried pasting an OpenBSD fdisk listing in here but it's a whole 80 characters wide and the web page wouldn't take it.

Answer (score 0):

The term head generally isn’t referring to the actual physical head, but rather the two sides of the platter. So C,H,S can be thought of as P,T,S (platter, track, sector). First it’s narrowed now to a specific layer, the the radial track from the centre of the disk to the outside, then the individual sector. On a floppy it’s similar but there are no platters so you just use T.S (track, sector)